# Memory leak when using accelerometerData

Tags: memory-leaks

```
@property (nonomic,retain) CMMotionManager *motionManager;  //delcare as a property.

motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init]; //init it.

motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.2f;
```

All below perform in a thread(not main thread).

```
-(void)handle{

    [motionManager startAccelerometerUpdates];
    while (1) {
        CMAcceleration acceleration = motionManager.accelerometerData.acceleration;
        NSLog(@"%f %f %f",acceleration.x,acceleration.y,acceleration.z);
        sleep(0.5);
    }
}
```

When I run the app in Xcode -> Instruments, I found the Living Memory increase uninterruptly,
until the app recieved memory warming and killed by system.
    I try to relase the accelerometerData in while block. but make no effect. motionManager.accelerometerData release];

I don't wish to use startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                                        withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData,NSError *error),  becuase I want to run it in background,and this block make no function when the app be suspended.

```
Can anyone help me?  

screenshot image:http://img.blog.csdn.net/20130702120140593
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using ARC? You should use it.

You must also make sure your bakground thread has an autorelease pool in place. The syntax for creating an autorelease pool with ARC enabled is `@autorelease { ... }` and the syntax without ARC is `NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; ... [pool release];`.

Apple has excellent documentation on how autorelease pools work. One is created automatically for the main thread but you must manually create it for background threads. You need to spend a couple of hours learning how it works, it's mandatory learning for any obj-c programmer.

Without seeing all your code, I can't tell you how it needs to work... but most likely the block or method you create the thread with needs it's contents wrapped in an autorelease pool and also the contents of your `while` loop needs a second autorelease pool.

---

EDIT: now that I've seen your code, you here is an example of how @autoreleasepool must be used to avoid leaking memory. I added line 6 and 23 to this code: https://gist.github.com/abhibeckert/5907754

I haven't tested, but that should solve your problem. It will definitely leak memory without those autorelease pools.

Basically if you have a background thread or long while loop, each needs to have it's own autorelease pool. I recommend reading this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html

Comment: I try to use @autorelease { ... } or NSAutoreleasePool,but the problem always exist.  My project url: http://qq644531343.opendrive.com/files/Ml8yMjE0NjY3MV9kY2NUQl9mYWQ3/Testautoreleasepool.zip

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem has been solved by your way.